# Golang local import

Tags: go, import

I am attempting to do a local import but it fails.

My environment is:

`echo $GOPATH
/home/peter/go
echo $GOROOT
/usr/local/go`

The entry point is:

/home/peter/go/src/projects/pkgs1/main.go

The imported file is:

/home/peter/go/src/projects/pkgs2/stuff.go

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "projects/pkgs2"  // <- this does not resolve
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println("123")
    pkgs2.X()
}
```

stuff.go

```
package pkgs2

import "fmt"

func X(){
    fmt.Println("X")
}
```

Any pointers on what I do wrong?

Comment: What does `but it fails` mean? What does the compiler say?`

Comment: The compiler says cannot resolve "projects" which is in the src folder

~/go/src/projects/pkgs2$ pwd
/home/peter/go/src/projects/pkgs2

Comment: FYI: (1) `x` is unexported so you won't be able to call it even if your import worked. (2) The call `x()` is unqualified, to reference an imported identifier you have to qualify it by prepending the package name, just like you're doing with `fmt.Println` by prepending the package name `fmt` to the identifier `Println`. So *export* your identifiers and then *qualify* them if you use them.

Comment: have you tried giving the complete path from home?

Comment: @user8351493 that's not how Go's `import` statements work.

Answer (score 2):

Your import path is correct and should resolve successfully, but as written, your program won't compile because the import isn't being used and there is no local function named `x`.

As mentioned by mkopriva your `x` function in pkgs2 isn't exported and you have not qualified it when trying to use it in your main package.

To export a function, it needs to start with a capital letter.

To use the function in another package, you need to prefix the package name to the function name.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "projects/pkgs2"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println("123")
    pkgs2.X()
}
```

stuff.go

```
package pkgs2

import "fmt"

func X(){
    fmt.Println("X")
}
```

Comment: The code is modified for export of X(), see above. I also tried the absolute path which was not allowed. The error remains: "Cannot resolve directory projects".

Comment: How are you compiling/running this? Are you using an IDE? Some IDE's run in a shell with independent environment variables.  What if you cd into you pkgs1 folder and type `GOPATH=/home/peter/go/ go run main.go`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I use Jetbrains Goland.  After I cd into pkgs1 folder and type GOPATH=/home/peter/go/ go run main.go it works as expected.

Comment: In goland you need to set the GOPATH in preferences->go. You can set the GOROOT too, although that’s optional.